# assigning a very big hexadecimal to a char through \u or \x

Tags: c#, unicode, char

```
char k = '\u103BD';
```

I get a **compile time error**.
I want to put the following char in my char `k` but it seems that the escape sequence will not accept more than `4` digits.
What should I do in this case?
[image]

Comment: `char` in C# represents one UTF16LE code unit. U+103BD does not fit in one code unit. Use a string instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character `char` is *two bytes* value, that's why it can be within `[\u0000..\uFFFF]` range only.
If you are looking for values *beyond* `\uFFFF`, please note, that it should be represented as *two characters* construction, e.g. `string`:

```
string result = "\U000103BD"; // note Capital U, 8 hex digits

Console.Write(result);
```

**Output:**

If you want to work with these two characters explicitly you can use the decoding below:

```
public static (char left, char right) Decode(int code) {
  if (code < 0x10000)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(code));

  return (
    (char)(((code - 0x10000) >> 10) + 0xD800),
    (char)(((code - 0x10000) & 0b1111_111_111) + 0xDC00)
  );
}
```

**Demo:**

```
(char left, char right) = Decode(0x103BD);

Console.Write(string.Concat(left, right));
```

**Output:**

Finally, from **.Net 6** on you can use [Rune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=net-6.0) structure to operate with these character pairs:

```
Rune rune = new Rune(0x103BD);

Console.Write(rune);
```

**Output:**